# Client services are not connecting to eureka server in kubernetes cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, kubernetes, netflix-eureka

When I run client service, I get these errors

```
 Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://shop-registry-0.shop-registry:8761/eureka/}, exception=I/O error on POST request for "http://shop-registry-0.shop-registry:8761/eureka/apps/PRODUCT-SERVICE": shop-registry-0.shop-registry stacktrace=org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://shop-registry-0.shop-registry:8761/eureka/apps/PRODUCT-SERVICE": shop-registry-0.shop-registry
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.createResourceAccessException(RestTemplate.java:888)
```

Configmap
[image]

Statefulset for Eureka
[image]

Eureka clients configuration
[image]

Eureka server configuration
[image]